# A Simple Puzzle - A bus Driver

Tags: lateral-thinking, story

So imagine you are a bus driver.

You have left the depo at 9:00 AM on the dot!

You arrive at the first stop, open the doors and pick up the 3 people waiting at the stop.

At the next stop 2 Adults and 3 Children get on.

The third stop - and twice as many people get off as get on. 2 People get on.

At the next stop the children get off with 1 adult.

At the final stop everyone has got to get off, the last person on the bus wanted to complement the driver and asked for his name.

What is the driver's name?

Comment: It's definitely just a rewording of this common riddle.

Comment: By the time of writing this there are 18208 different solutions to this puzzle (and the corresponding person being able to post it here). I would mark it as too broad :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer is

> AeJey

Because

> I am the bus driver (Since I am imagining that I am the bus driver)

Comment: yeah, i did say it was simple, but it's a nice riddle :D

Comment: no...WRONG...in my opinion answer is 'manshu' :D